# Is there a way for me to use the router.query in next js in a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

So I have this Next.js page.
I'm trying to use the request params and use it in a function, but for some reason it's always undefined. I've tried everything I know.

- I know that I don't need to put the `id` in the function.
- I tried using the router in `useEffect`, wouldn't work.

Here's my code :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useRouter  } from 'next/router'
import axios from 'axios';

export default function id () {
    const [ response, setResponse ] = useState("");
    const router = useRouter();
    const id = router.query.id;
    const testFunction = (id) => {
        console.log(id);
    }
    useEffect((id) => {
        testFunction();
    }, [])
    return (
    <div>
    <p>params: {id}</p>
    </div>
  ) 
}
```

Comment: Try adding `id` to the `useEffect`'s dependency array, and also pass it to the `testFunction` call, i.e. `testFunction(id);`.

Comment: *"I'm trying to use the request params and use it in a function"*, in what function are you trying to use it? The only function you are calling in this code is `testFunction` and you are not passing `id` to that.

Answer (score 1):

First thing first, you need to name your file with the name of your parameter, (example: `[id].tsx`)

[image: example]

Note: If you put it inside a folder (like the image), the path will be `http://localhost:3000/folder-name/your-param`

And then, try this code:

```
import React from 'react'

id.getInitialProps = ({ query }:any) => {
    const { id } = query
    return { id }
}

export default function id({id}:any) {
    console.log(id); // You can use the query outside the return by calling `id`
    return (
        <div>
            <p>params: {id}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: i don't have it in a folder, i want it to be localhost:3000/@username,

Comment: Take a look at this code : 

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useRouter  } from 'next/router'
import axios from 'axios';

export default function id () {
    const [ response, setResponse ] = useState("");
    const router = useRouter();
    const id = router.query["@id"];
    return (
      <div>
    <p>params: {id}</p>
    </div>
  ) 
}
```
It works just fine. but i still can't use the id anywhere but in the return

Comment: @lunix of course you can't use it. To do that you need to store the query before the `return()`. I have updated my answer for that.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
    import { useRouter  } from 'next/router'
    import axios from 'axios';
    
    export default function id () {
        const [ response, setResponse ] = useState("");
        const router = useRouter();
        const id = router.query.id;
        const testFunction = (id) => {
            console.log(id);
        }
        useEffect((id) => {
            testFunction();
        }, [router])
        return (
        <div>
        <p>params: {id}</p>
        </div>
      ) 
    }
```